# ¿Cómo agregar un texto o distintivo de "envio gratis" sobre el título de los productos que tienen método de envío gratis en woocommerce?

Tags: php, javascript, woocommerce

Como se ve en la imagen, quisiera agregar un mensaje sobre el título del producto, un tercer div que tenga el mensaje "este producto cuenta con envío gratis". Este mensaje solo tiene que aparecer cuando el producto tenga metodo de envío gratis, o pertenezca a una categoría específica como "envío gratis". Pueden revisar la página [aquí](https://suplementosallfitness.cl/comprar/c4-original-315-grs/).

[image: Captura]

-Ya pude agregar el texto con este código:
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','texto_envio',3);

```
function texto_envio() {
echo '<div class="envio-gratis">
        <p>ENVIO GRATIS A TODO CHILE</p>
        </div>';
}
```

Pero se ve en todos los productos, la idea es que se vea solo en los productos que tengan envío gratis. Por favor, si alguien me puede ayudar con esto.

No se mucho de programación pero se me imagina que algo asi deberia ser:

```
if (is_product() is_product_category ('envios-gratis')){
    echo '<div class="envio-gratis">
        <p>ENVIO GRATIS A TODO CHILE</p>
        </div>';
} 
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'texto_envio', 3 );
```

Comment: yo no entiendo mucho de estoy miro copio y pego en realidad, donde es que pones el codigo ?? yo recien puse la 2da parte de tu codigo en el archivo funtion de mi tema pero me lo hace q

Answer (score -1):

Buscando info sobre como es el tema de las funciones y filtros en este mudo que para mi es completamente nuevo , logre armar una cadena que me resulto yo tengo envíos gratis de 3000$ en adelante y con el siguiente código me funciona, espero te sea útil.

```
// Mostrar envio gratis para productos de mas de $3000 
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'ddw_if_no_price_woo', 100, 2); 
function ddw_if_no_price_woo($price, $product) { 
    if ($product->price >= 3000) { 
       return $price.'<br><b><span style="color: red;"> Envío gratis</sspan></b>'; 
    } else { 
       return $price; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Eliminé el medio de contacto pues no es correcto ni necesario, si tienes la solución publicala aquí por favor y aquí puedes leer [answer]

Comment: y como publico el codigo en la respuesta  no entiendo, lo intente varias veces pero me pone solo una parte y el resto marca error , me gano